# Computed variable for every repeater row shows up in the next row

Tags: asp.net, .net, data-binding, repeater

I have a protected variable and used in a repeater itemtemplate, <%# Bonus %> which is calculated in the repeater's OnItemDataBound event based on other columns' values in the same row.

The problem is that the Bonus value for a row is showing in the next row. So for row #1, the value is blank. The second row shows the bonus for row #1, third row shows bonus value for second row and so on. The bound values are showing fine. It's the computed value showing in the wrong row.

It seems in the OnItemDataBound event the computed value is calculated but for some reason, the value is not used in the rendering of the current row but in the next row.

What am I doing wrong?

**Updated**

Simplified sample code:

```
   .......
    protected Decimal Bonus;
    .....
    (then inside repeater OnItemDataBound handler)
.....
    DataRowView row = (DataRowView) e.Item.DataItem;
    Bonus = Convert.ToInt32(row["salary"]) * .01;



     in ASPx:
    .....
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <td><%# Eval("salary") %>   <== will show correct value
    </td>
    <td><#% Bonus %>            <== doesn't show the bonus computed for that row from OnItemDataBound handler. Shows up in the next repeater row.
    </td>
<ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: row# start from 0. can you show your code

Comment: @Rab There are no row numbers involved. See provided code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`OnItemDataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.onitemdatabound.aspx) occurs after the row is bound.

All the values of the current row are present in the parameters to the function.

If you need to set a new value, since the repeater is not going to bind the values again after this function, you should set the text of the control yourself.

```
  void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(Object Sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {

      // This event is raised for the header, the footer, separators, and items.

      // Execute the following logic for Items and Alternating Items.
      if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) {

         if (((Evaluation)e.Item.DataItem).Rating == "Good") {
            ((Label)e.Item.FindControl("BonusLabel")).Text= Bonus.ToString();
         }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to a method that performs the calculation:

**code-behind**

```
public string CalculateBonus(object salaryValue)
{
    int salary;
    string bonus;
    if (Int32.TryParse(salaryValue.ToString(), out salary))
    {
        bonus = (salary * .01).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        bonus = "N/A"; //or whatever default value you want to return
    }
    return bonus;
}
```

**aspx page**

```
<td><%# CalculateBonus(Eval("Salary")) %></td>
```